# Differentiating between send or received email

Tags: c#, .net, email, mimekit, eml

i am developing an application which reads .eml files and extract their data and does some processes with these data with c# 
i am using **MimeKit** package. how can I differentiate between sent or received email?

here is part of my code:

```
private static List<List<string>> GetNextMail(string emlFile, int mailNumber)
{
    try
    {
        // eml file is the path of eml
        var mimeMessage = MimeMessage.Load(emlFile);
        return GetNextMail(mimeMessage,mailNumber);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

how can I use `mimeMessage` object for differentiating between sent or receive emails?

Comment: In which context does the application run? If it runs for a user/organisation you could analyze the from-address and either compare it to the user's mail address or against the domain of the company (in the simplest case like: ends with "@myorganisiation.com" or with a regex for more complex cases).

Comment: The `.eml` format does not contain this information. That having been said, *received* mail will usually contain `Received: ...` headers and *sent* mail won't, so you might use that as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Inbox folder will contain receiving mail.